Identify 6-PIN SMD Marked 60AH from mini UV transillumination
Help me to identify integrated circuit 6-PIN SMD Marked 60AH from Mini UV transillumination. I've been googling for it but no one matched it. It seems like hidden mark before 60AH but I no have idea. Can anyone solve it?


The dimensions are consistent with SOT23-6:
The part has a size of 2.9 mm Body Lenght, 1.6 mm Body Width, and 0.95 mm Pitch.

(Source: infineon.com)

Please provide additional context: what part of the circuit is it in,  what other components is it connected to, etc.

Please provide pitch and dimensions.

@brhans it's connected to capasitor, diode, fuse, resistor, and power transistor

@VoltageSpike i was added photo

@VoltageSpike I think the question should be reopened and I can give an answer.

@nanash1 dimensions have not been provided. The community in the meta has indicated that dimensions are required for these types of identification questions

@pjbenzz Provide the dimensions and I will answer the question if it's a SOT23-6 package.

@nanash1 that's right it's same like SOT23-6 dimensions

@pjbenzz You should edit this into the question with the explicit dimensions in mm and summit it for review. I can only answer the question when it gets reopened.

@nanash1 edited done

@pjbenzz I'm sorry, but that's still not quite right. You now have a picture without a source in the question which is also against the rules. All you really had to add was a line of text like: The part has a size of 1.5 mm x 3 mm with a 1 mm pitch. It's consistent with SOT23-6.

@pjbenzz I added the source for you.

@nanash1 I'm sorry. I'm so confuse because i'm newbiee. now i added text " The part has a size of 2.9 mm Body Lenght, 1.6 mm Body Width, and 0.95 mm Pitch. " in question. It's that right now?

@pjbenzz It should be ok now, but your measurements are suspiously specific. Did you really measure the pitch as 0.95 mm or did just copy that from the random Infineon datasheet?

@nanash1 it's from your source

Given the placement of surrounding components, a DC-DC regulator. Perhaps that can narrow down your search. Probably a buck.

It's an Onsemi FL7760A constant current buck LED controller.


(Source: lcsc.com)
